# Java : How to read input without knowing number of input lines and size both?

Tags: java, input, output

input<1>

```
Hello World

ABC DE
```

output<1>

```
Hello World

ABC DE
```

---

input<2>

```
Hello World

hi hi hi

blabla bla
```

output<2>

```
Hello World

hi hi hi

blabla bla
```

**The problem is... When two lines are input, two lines must be output at once, and if three lines are input, three lines must be output at once. The examples are above.**

This is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String input = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

At this time, if I enter one line, that line prints immediately.

I don't know how to solve this problem...

Comment: You ought to be able to google and find the answer to this question. That said you need to put the readline() and println into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop, in which you read lines from the inputStream and store the read lines into an arrayList. After reading the lines you loop over the arrayList and print the lines out.

```
arrayList<String> result = new arrayList<>();
boolean read = true;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
while(read){
    String input = br.readLine();
    if(input.equals('')){
        read = false;
    } else {
        result.add(input);
    }
}
for(int i = 0 ; i< result.length() ; i++){
    System.out.println(input[i]);
}
```